# How can I type approximate equal sign in markdown jupyter

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write following approximate equation in jupyter markdown.
this is what I have tried: g$\approx$f

I want to know if the syntax I used is the best way to write the equation?
And is there any document for markdown mathematic syntax I can reference?

Thanks:)

[image]

Comment: Like the answer below, I can run your code perfectly fine. All you need to know about the syntax is that anything between the $ signs is interpreted as latex. A full Jupyter markdown reference is here: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html

Answer (score 4):

If the above doesn't work, you may want to try double backslashes, as in some contexts they need to be escaped:

`display(Markdown('$1.0-q \\approx 0.99,0.5,0.0$'))`

Comment: Can you explain? Or, provide a reference to some user guide?